# Onclick to next HTML page not working inside radio-toolbar div tag

Tags: html, css, radio-button

When I run this code not using the div tag radio-toolbar the onlclick function to another page (Using StackOverflow homepage as example) works. When I add in the div tag radio-toolbar in order to design the radio buttons, the onlick does not work.

Here is the HTML and CSS without the div tag radio-toolbar...

```css
<style>
  #main_page {
  background: #34357c;
  padding: 10px 20px 30px 20px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top:315px; 
  margin-left: 415px;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id= "main_page">

<input type = "radio" id = "ID1" value = "Husband" onclick = "window.location.href = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com'"><label>Husband</label>
<input type = "radio" id = "ID2" value = "Wife" onclick = "window.location.href = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com'"><label>wife</label>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I add in the div tag Radio-toolbar in order to style the radio buttons the onlick feature to another html does not work...

```css
<style>
          #main_page {
          background: #34357c;
          padding: 10px 20px 30px 20px;
          width: 900px;
          height: 600px;
          font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
          position: fixed;
          z-index: -1;
          margin-top:315px; 
          margin-left: 415px;
          }
    
        .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
            margin-top: 25px !important;
            opacity: 0 
         }
        
        .radio-toolbar label {
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 50px;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size:25px;
            border: 2px solid #444;
            width: 110px;
            height: 110px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            background: #daeaff;
            color: #4c4de4;
           }
        
        .radio-toolbar label:hover {
          background-color: #white;
          color: #DDDDDD;
        }
 </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
             
        
        </head>
        <body>

    <div id= "main_page">
    
    <div class = "radio-toolbar">
    
    
    <input type = "radio" id = "ID1" value = "Husband" onclick = "window.location.href = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com'"><label>Husband</label>
    <input type = "radio" id = "ID2" value = "Wife" onclick = "window.location.href = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com'"><label>wife</label>

    </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

When using the Code snippets you can see in the first one that clicking on one of the radio buttons produces an action, whereas in the second code snippet nothing happens after clicking on the radio buttons.

Appreciate the help!

EDIT: Thank you @DCR for helping make the question more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to place the onclick event on the label since you hide the radio button

```css
<style>
          #main_page {
          background: #34357c;
          padding: 10px 20px 30px 20px;
          width: 900px;
          height: 600px;
          font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
          position: fixed;
          z-index: -1;
          margin-top:315px; 
          margin-left: 415px;
          }
    
        .radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
            margin-top: 25px !important;
            opacity: 0 
         }
        
        .radio-toolbar label {
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 50px;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size:25px;
            border: 2px solid #444;
            width: 110px;
            height: 110px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            background: #daeaff;
            color: #4c4de4;
           }
        
        .radio-toolbar label:hover {
          background-color: #white;
          color: #DDDDDD;
        }
 </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
             
        
        </head>
        <body>

    <div id= "main_page">
    
    <div class = "radio-toolbar">
    
    
    <input type = "radio" id = "ID1" value = "Husband" ><label onClick = "window.location.href = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com'">Husband</label>
    <input type = "radio" id = "ID2" value = "Wife" ><label onClick = "window.location.href = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com'">wife</label>

    </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your hrefs to https://www.stackoverflow.com so they would work in the snippet.  It works here, wehat error or problem are you having

```css
<style>
  #main_page {
  background: #34357c;
  padding: 10px 20px 30px 20px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 600px;
  font-family: 'roboto', sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top:315px; 
  margin-left: 415px;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id= "main_page">

<input type = "radio" id = "ID1" value = "Husband" onclick = "window.location.href = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com'"><label>Husband</label>
<input type = "radio" id = "ID2" value = "Wife" onclick = "window.location.href = 'https://www.stackoverflow.com'"><label>wife</label>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The first code snippet works fine, but if you try the second code snippet, and add https://www.stackoverflow.com, it does not work.

Comment: see solution below